# Making quicksort with pointers

Tags: pointers, segmentation-fault, quicksort

Hey im trying to make a quick sort function with pointers, im pretty limited in pointer knowledge. I'm receiving a segmentation-fault for the code, I know that means im trying to map values outside of my array range but i cant seem to solve the issue. Any help would be appreciated! Even if you don't want to answer it pointing me in the right direction is always appreciated!

I do have a main function where this is called and it is initialized.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void quicksort_time(int *first,int *last){
int *pivot,*j,*temp,*i;
// The Quick Sorting algorithim is below! 
 if(first<last){
     *pivot=*first;
     *i=*first;
     *j=*last;

     while(i<j){
         while(i<=pivot&&i<last)
             i++;
         while(j>pivot)
             j--;
         if(i<j){
             *temp=*i;
              *i=*j;
              *j=*temp;
         }
     }

     *temp=*pivot;
     *pivot=*j;
     *j=*temp;
     quicksort_time(first,j-1);
     quicksort_time(j+1,last);

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Turn compiler warnings on!

```
foo.c: In function ‘quicksort_time’:
foo.c:12:12: warning: ‘pivot’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
      *pivot=*first;
            ^
foo.c:13:8: warning: ‘i’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
      *i=*first;
        ^
foo.c:14:8: warning: ‘j’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
      *j=*last;
        ^
foo.c:22:19: warning: ‘temp’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
              *temp=*i;
                   ^
```